# Error when opening the Docker in Windows 10- /sigterm error exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation: pipe hasn't been connected yet

Tags: docker, hypervisor, sigterm

Error when opening the Docker in Windows 10- /sigterm error exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation: pipe hasn't been connected yet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN85x.png)

Tried by resetting the Docker to factory details, facing an issue- Windows Hypervisor is not present.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNRur.png)